# Create multiple viewports in minecraft?

Tags: rendering, minecraft-modding, modding, viewport

Im new to minecraft modding, but Im curious about the possibility of creating a mod such that players could set up a 'security camera' with its own viewport so that the player could 'see what the camera sees'. For example, imagine a minimap style window that displays the viewport of the camera you've setup.

**Specific questions:**

1. can you have a second viewport that isnt tied to the player?
2. Can you programmatically access a viewport? e.g. store the pixel values to a variable rather directly rendering to the screen.

Comment: yeah you can, you'll need to render the world twice (fps cost), you can render directly to the overlay part I'd have to boot up forge to make sure though

Comment: Hmm, I saw someone writing something sort of like this in the forge IRC. IIRC, they were testing an ingame MC computer's "graphics card" by rendering a camera view onto the computer's screen in-game. I'll have to try to dig that up.